# Sending a Jackson converted string or JSON object to HTML page using thyemeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, json, jackson, thymeleaf

I'm trying to send a JSON object to a property in javascript using thymeleaf, but when the value is received, all the quotes are converted to ".

In my POJO, I have the following method:

```
public class MyObject {

   public String toJSON() throws IOException {
        StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
        if (this.getCaseRegistrations().size() > 0) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.writeValue(result, this.caseRegistrations);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

And elsewhere, that class is created and ready to use and sent to the ModelAndView in the Spring controller:
`mav.addObject("myObject", myObject);`

In my html page, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
       let registrations = [[ ${myObject.toJSON()} ]]
       console.log(registrations);
  });
```

Unfortunately, when this runs, javascript fails on the assignment with a complaint about `&`.  Looking at the Source, I see the following:
 `let registrations = [{&quot;prop1&quot;:&quot;val1&quot;, ...}];`

When I look at the string on the java side (in debug mode), the value looks correct
 `[{ "prop1": "val1", ...}]`

I've tried various things, such as `let registrations = '[[ ${myObject.toJSON()} ]]'` (using the backquote here) and let `registrations = decudeURI[[ ${myObject.toJSON()} ]])` and `[# th:utext="${myObject.toJSON()}"/];`.  That last attempt (with th:utext), failed completely.

What is the proper way to convert a POJO to a JSON and the assign it to a variable in javascript on an html page? (Java-Spring-Thymeleaf)

Comment: Why are you using a custom method and not just `let registrations = [[ ${myObject} ]]` (with `th:inline="javascript"` on your script tag)? Thymeleaf will auto serialize to json without any kind of helper methods.  See this: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#advanced-inlined-evaluation-and-javascript-serialization

Comment: When I do that, I get the memory location of the object and not the actual data. I suppose I could have been more clear on that. The `MyObject` class has, as properties, objects to other custom classes. So, the output of using [[]] was Prop1@32BA5CD, Prop2@88CA65B, etc.

Comment: did you make sure and add `th:inline="javascript"` to your script tag like the documentation?

Comment: I think that might have been my solution.  There's a difference between `th:inline="javascript"`, `type="text/javascript`, and `language="javascript"`.

Answer (score 0):

i dont have much experience in this tech but i can help you to give scenario is that

1. Capture the json data before sending to js.
2. then use something like `strrplace()` i dont if you know some another function [http://w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp] look ta here it will replace all the brackets. see first argument will be what you want to replace and second will be with what you want replace .

in my case it was like,

```
$user=str_replace("'[',']','{','}'",(my json variable data));
```